# Load different EJS, depending on URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, ejs

If the URL contains 'todos', for example, '.../todos/*', he should load a different EJS template (todos.ejs). If the URL doesn’t contain 'todos', the normal index.ejs will load.

I tried something like below, but I think the use of `app.get` is wrong.

```
if (req.url.indexOf("todos") >= 0) {
    app.get('/todos/*', function(req, res) {
        res.render('todos', {
            title: 'todos page'
        });
    });
} else {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'index page'
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions to match URL paths](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-paths) with Express, so:

```
// Match any URL with '/todos/' in the path:
app.get(/\/todos\//, function(req, res) {
  res.render('todos', { title: 'todos page' });
});

// Match the rest:
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'index page' });
});
```

If you don't care about the slashes surrounding *"todos*", the match becomes this:

```
app.get(/todos/, ...);
```

Note that the order of declaring route handlers matters: you want to declare the most specific match (the "todos" one) first, least specific ("the rest") last.

Comment: Thanks for that clean solution. It is working in general, but... All along I used `/` instead of `*`, which worked. **Using `*`**, express or ejs has a **problem with external scripts/stylesheets**. For example, `<link ... href="css/style.css"/>` I get `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:1337/css/style.css".`

Comment: @ChrisEbert that would depend on the order of declaration again. If you use `express.static()` to handle JS/CSS, be sure that it's declared before any of your regular routes. Also, you should probably use absolute paths in JS/CSS URL's (starting with a `/`).

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like this.

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    if (req.url.indexOf("todos") >= 0) {
        return res.render('todos', {
           title: 'todos page'
        });
    } 

    res.render('todos', {
        title: 'todos page'
    });
});
```

Comment: You can do the * part and override the todos part later also.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  if (req.url.indexOf('todos') === -1) {
    return res.render('index', { title: 'index page'})
  } 
  else {
    return res.render('todos', { title: 'todos page' })
  }
})
```